# How do I pop and unshift that value to an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I have an array of 26 letters, I want to `pop` the last letter and `unshift` it to the same array. The aim of this is to create a rotating array to simulate a rotor in an enigma machine as it "steps".

I have the ciphers working fine and a way to reset the arrays to their original configuration using `useState`, however when it comes to the `pop` and `unshift` I am having issues, I am aware that react doesn't like destructive methods of array manipulation. So I am trying to work out how to mimic these in react within a `useState` funciton.

I have tried the `pop` and `unshift` without any help so switched to `setState` as shown below:

```
    setRotar1((prevArray) => {
        const lastLetter = prevArray.pop();
        return [lastLetter, ...prevArray];
    });
```

When checking the console logs however, the new array is returning the 2nd to last letter at the 0th index. The log has also removed the original last letter entirely.

```
i.e. [a, b, c, d, e, f]  
should return [f, a, b, c, d, e]  
actually returns [e, a, b, c, d]
```

I am sure that there is an issue with how the setRotar1 function works but being new to react I am not sure how to manage this properly. I apologize if there has been a question like this before but I cant seem to find a solution.

Edit: Have now got the arrays functioning correctly, thankyou for all the help!

Comment: your code should not be doing what you describe. Please post a full runable example that can exhibit the issue. Currently the issue must lie somewhere else. Additionally, a non destructive way would be to skip the `pop` and do `return [...prevArray.slice(-1), ...prevArray.slice(0,-1)]`

Comment: I added code to mimic your code to my little test project, like this

******
const [rotar1, setRotar1] = useState(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] )

const testfunc = () => {
 console.log('testfunc')
  setRotar1((prevArray) => {
        const lastLetter = prevArray.pop();
        return [lastLetter, ...prevArray];
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
 console.log('rotar1', rotar1)
}, [rotar1])


*******

and it works fine. Please provide more complete example.

Comment: Thankyou for the responses, I noticed that you added the useEffect hook, I shall look into that and see if that is the cause as I havent used it as of yet and I imagine that that is what my issue is. Thankyou!

Comment: I don't know how it would help you, since useEffect in this case only prints console.log. useEffect reacts to changes of the state, but in this case I didn't alter state through it. If you don't manage to solve the issue, you should provide more complete code.

Comment: Sorry yes, you are correct, I have just been looking at any possible thing  that I have missed, I will be reading through every line of code again and trying to work out test cases, the frustration I have is that with 3 separate rotars with 3 separate ciphers have been a nightmare to handle.  They work fine, I have a feeling its the indexing that is the issue so have been trying to work the maths correctly in the ciphers and had the idea of just rotating the arrays themselves to represent the stepping instead, I will try to get a sandbox going soon though and will edit the post when I have.

Comment: The repository is at https://github.com/Jaycossey/Portfolio/blob/main/Portfolio_Website/components/EnigmaFullScreen.jsx

i apologise for the mess of the code itself, still a work in progress for my portfolio and I know I need to clear it all up but I either want to edit the shiftRotars function to manipulate the arrays or I want to change the maths on the substitutionCiphers to reflect the index of the letters that would be needed to accurately decipher the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I am also attaching a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-frost-4xgmcg?file=/src/App.js

```
   setArray([array[array.length - 1], ...array.slice(0, -1)]);
```

Comment: Thankyou! I shall try this, I am trying to figure out the decryption of the enigma as a letter gets passed back through the machine, I have been trying with indexes but for whatever reason I cant seem to get the maths correct, thought that if I rotate the array itself it may help so I will see how this effects the code and let everyone know

Comment: This works perfectly thankyou! I can figure out why the substitution ciphers arent updating the stepping from here!

Comment: @Jaycossey - My pleasure. Can you please accept this as correct answer?